# Acceleration statistics at thermal equilibrium for a simple atomic system

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, acceleration

Consider a case of a simple liquid, say argon or Lennard--Jones potential.

What are the statistical properties of acceleration at equilibrium? For example, acceleration distribution or a correlation function. Is there a general theory/expressions for that, like for position/momenta?

I know one can relate a mean square force to the temperature to calculate temperature in a Monte Carlo simulation (when the particles' momenta are not known), anything else?